# Volume Distribution of Bound Charge in an Isotropic Dielectric: when does $ \nabla \cdot \vec{E }=0$?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, gauss-law, dielectric

In Electricity and Magnetism by Bleaney & Bleaney (3rd Ed.) pg 18 they state:

> In a dielectric where $ \chi_e $ (the susceptibility) is uniform, isotropic and independent of field strength there is no volume distribution of charge... This follows from the fact that $ \nabla \cdot \vec{E} =0$...

I have assumed that volume distribution of charge means volume distribution of *bound* charge, but perhaps I am wrong.

I am a little confused as:

$ \vec{D} = \epsilon \vec{E} $  (for a simple dielectric)

$\implies \nabla \cdot \vec{ E }= \frac{\nabla \cdot \vec{ D} }{\epsilon} $

from Gauss' theorem $ \nabla \cdot \vec {D} = \rho_{free} $

hence $ \nabla\cdot \vec{ E }= 0 \ \mathrm{iff} \ \rho_{free} = 0 $

so is the statement in Bleaney & Bleaney only true if there is no free charge in the dielectric? If my working is incorrect please let me know how / where I have gone wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Your working is correct for free charges, but what about the bound ones? Generally (without making any assumptions about the dielectric's properties), we can write:

$$\vec{D}=\varepsilon_0\vec{E}+\vec{P}$$

where $\vec{P}$ is dielectric's polarization density. The bound charge density can be obtained using:

$$\rho_b = -\vec{\nabla}\cdot \vec{P}$$

so let us calculate this and see what we get. We can substitute $\vec{D}=\varepsilon \vec{E}$ in the definition of the electric displacement field ($\vec{D}$) so we can obtain $\vec{P}$ in terms of the electric field:

$$\varepsilon \vec{E}=\varepsilon_0\vec{E}+\vec{P}$$

Reordering the terms and taking the divergence of both sides:

$$\vec{\nabla}\cdot \vec{P}=(\varepsilon-\varepsilon_0)\vec{\nabla}\cdot \vec{E}=-\rho_b=0$$

Therefore, the bound charge density must also be zero! Combining the conclusion you reached with the one I obtained, we can write:

$$\rho_{total}=\rho_{free}+\rho_b=0$$

Comment: Thanks for the working! I am still a little confused though: is the assumption that the free charge = 0 necessary for the conclusion that the bound charge = 0 (In the textbook, it almost sounds like the bound charge = 0 no matter what free charge is placed inside the dielectric, which doesnt make sense to me) i.e. is div E = 0 only when the free charge is 0?

Comment: I think the problem comes from confusion with Maxwell's laws. $\vec{\nabla}\cdot \vec{E}=\frac{\rho_{total}}{\varepsilon_0}$, so this is only true if the total charge density is zero. Therefore, both free and bound charge densities must be zero

Comment: But then surely the statement in the textbook would be quite unusual, because it would be saying "the bound charge is zero because div E is 0 (which is only true if the bound charge is 0)".

Comment: I think I understand now: should I really be reading it "in order for a dielectric's susceptibility to be uniform, isotropic & independent of E, then we must have that both $\rho_{free}$ and $\rho_{bound}$ are 0" ?